# synchronous keystroke reading from console application

Tags: c, windows, linux

I want to read every keystroke from a console application written in c under windows and linux immediately. Unfortunately the function gets(line) does only return a value, when the "enter/return" key is pressed. 
I'm looking for a function that returns immediately after a key has been pressed.

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
char cTmp[MAX_LINE];
char line[MAX_LINE];
while( gets(line) != NULL) {
    sprintf(cTmp,"Characters entered: %c", line);
    puts(cTmp);
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but wouldn't getc() do that?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for `getch()`. On Windows (at least VC++) it's declared in `<conio.h>`. On Linux it's part of curses.

Comment: actually getc() is part of stdio

Comment: @Murali VP: Yes, getc is part of stdio -- but it won't do what he wants (at least on any implementation I've seen). Even though it only reads a single character, it requires the user to press the return/enter key before it does so. `getch` is *not* part of stdio, but it does what he wants -- reads a single character *without* waiting for the user to press return.

Comment: @Murali VP getc() is a stream function, and so won't have the desired behavior unless the terminal is reconfigured out of line mode.

Answer (score 2):

The following code worked for me. Thank you for pointing me into to right direction.
http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/503640-getch-linux

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int mygetch(void)
{
struct termios oldt,
newt;
int ch;
tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt );
newt = oldt;
newt.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt );
ch = getchar();
tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt );
return ch;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `getchar()` and `putchar()` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
char line[MAX_LINE];
int i = 0;
int c;
while ( (c = putchar(getchar())) != EOF)
{
    line[i] =c;
}
```